# Find exact word in file using egrep in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I have a file called `F1`. `F1` contains

```
Hello abc@
aaa ddd
```

Now, I want to check the word `abc` is in file `F1`.

After running the following command

```
find $dir -type f -exec egrep -w "abc" {} \;
```

This is the output I get

```
Hello abc@
```

For some reason the word `abc@` was also found. (I was looking for `abc`.)

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709912/how-to-grep-the-exact-match

Comment: it outputs the whole line by default.

Answer (score 4):

This should do it:

```
egrep '(^| )abc( |$)' F1
```

It looks for `abc` surrounded by either space or line beginning/ending.

Answer (score 2):

You're likely using GNU egrep - the `-w` option isn't part of the POSIX standard
- and its manual page states

```
-w, --word-regexp
      Select  only  those  lines  containing  matches  that form whole
      words.  The test is that the matching substring must  either  be
      at  the  beginning  of  the  line,  or  preceded  by  a non-word
      constituent character.  Similarly, it must be either at the  end
      of  the  line  or  followed by a non-word constituent character.
      Word-constituent  characters  are  letters,  digits,   and   the
      underscore.
```

So `@` is considered a non-word constituent character, just like `,` and `.` and
whitespace.

If you have an idea of what you'd like the word separators to be, let us know
and we can craft a regexp for you.

Comment: You absolutely right. I know that '@' is a non-word.
Space is the word separator.

Comment: So it's telling you that there's a match because there is one. You are looking for the word "abc".  Since `@` is not considered part of a word, it sees `abc@` as the word "abc" that you're looking for - incdentally followed by a `@`, but that doesn't change anything.
  So what exactly would constitute a match for you?

Comment: David, if your file had the strings `abc.`, `abc!`, `abc#`, `abc%`, `abc*`, `abc,`, `abc-`, and `abc?`, which of those would you want `egrep -w` to find and which would you want it to ignore?

Comment: I don't know Mark. 
All I know is that I want to be able to find out by given two inputs: a filepath and a word, weather or not the word is in the given file.

Comment: this should work find $dir -type f -exec grep -v [[:punct:]]  {} \; | grep abc

Answer (score 0):

```
find $dir -type f -exec grep -v [[:punct:]]  {} \; | grep -ow abc
```

Comment: No, still find 'abc@'.

Comment: can't be i'm getting this [root@rhce sto]# find . -type f -exec egrep -o "abc" {} \;
abc

Comment: The output I get is: 'abc'. But it shouldn't give any output.
Cause Iam looking for a word that doesn't exists in F1.

Comment: sorry, according to your question, you were looking for the word "abc" only ?

Comment: I want to know weather or not the word 'abc' exists in file F1.

Comment: try this  find $dir -type f -exec grep -v [[:punct:]]  {} \; | grep abc

Comment: ok, i edited my answer above. so that will be helpful to anyone else. cheers