# Regex in R: finding exact number

Tags: regex, r, string-matching

This is in R

```
grep("AB22", c("AB22" ,"AB22","AB22" ,"AB22+3" ,"AB226AEM+1","AB22AEM+2") , value=T)
```

gives all of them:
"AB22","AB22", "AB22" ,"AB22+3" ,"AB226AEM+1" ,"AB22AEM+2"

but, I want only "AB22","AB22","AB22" ,"AB22+3" ,AB22AEM+2" i.e. all the entries containing AB22 and not AB226 ot 2265...etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a job for [word boundary anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) and/or a [negative lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
grep("\\bAB22(?!\\d)", c("AB22" ,"AB22","AB22" ,"AB22+3" ,"AB226AEM+1","AB22AEM+2") , value=T, perl=TRUE);
```

`(?!\d)` means "Assert that it's impossible to match a digit after the current position".

Comment: Really appreciate your prompt reply Tim. But I also want AB22AEM+2 as the out put since it has AB22.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
grep("AB22[^0-9]|AB22$", c("AB22" ,"AB22","AB22" ,"AB22+3" ,"AB226AEM+1","AB22AEM+2") , value=T)
```

or shorter:

```
grep("AB22([^0-9]|$)", c("AB22" ,"AB22","AB22" ,"AB22+3" ,"AB226AEM+1","AB22AEM+2") , value=T)
```

if needed you can add the start anchor `^` at the begining.

Answer (score 0):

[How to make grep only match if the entire line matches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709912/how-to-grep-the-exact-match)

I think this post might be of some use.

Using anchors at the start(^) and end($) of your search string will limit grep to returning results that match your search string exactly.

```
grep("^AB22$", "AB22" ,"AB22","AB22".....
```