# How to grep exact word by using grep command

Tags: unix, grep

Eg- lets suppose I want to grep string `VR030315ITVENDMXN`. Then grep should not show `VR030315ITVENDMXN-LPP` or any additional things with `VR030315ITVENDMXN` .

Comment: please indicate some sample input and desired output, it is not very clear what you mean. Exact match or just print the match?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the -o (or --only-matching ) option in your command line option

Of you do not desire to have the filename displayed use the -h (--no-filename) option in addition to remove them.

Comment: $ grep --o "VR030315ITVENDMXN" *
LCDE.BLQSAM.OCAA2441.C0368800.B5C03O54:VR030315ITVENDMXN
LCDE.BLQSAM.OCAA2441.C0368802.B5C03Q32:VR030315ITVENDMXN
LCDE.BLQSAM.XMXA2441.C0368801.B5C03O55:VR030315ITVENDMXN
LCDE.BLQSAM.XMXA2441.C0368801.B5C03O55:VR030315ITVENDMXN
LCDE.BLQSAM.XMXA2441.C0368803.B5C03Q34:VR030315ITVENDMXN
LCDE.BLQSAM.XMXA2441.C0368803.B5C03Q34:VR030315ITVENDMXN

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I have tried below commands but no luck. :(
$ grep -o 'VR030315ITVENDMXN' *
LCDE.BLQSAM.OCAA2441.C0368800.B5C03O54:VR030315ITVENDMXN
LCDE.BLQSAM.OCAA2441.C0368802.B5C03Q32:VR030315ITVENDMXN
LCDE.BLQSAM.XMXA2441.C0368801.B5C03O55:VR030315ITVENDMXN
LCDE.BLQSAM.XMXA2441.C0368801.B5C03O55:VR030315ITVENDMXN
LCDE.BLQSAM.XMXA2441.C0368803.B5C03Q34:VR030315ITVENDMXN
LCDE.BLQSAM.XMXA2441.C0368803.B5C03Q34:VR030315ITVENDM

Comment: so it is the exact hit but with the filename and the line number location

Answer (score 0):

Can you use anchors?
For instance:

```
grep '^VR030315ITVENDMXN$' file
```

There is a similar question here [How to make grep only match if the entire line matches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709912/how-to-grep-the-exact-match)