# Grep exact match in line

Tags: grep

File1:

```
Btr_0449a   447
Btr_0449    447
```

Desired output:

```
Btr_0449    447
```

I want grep to find 'Btr_0449', not 'Btr_0449a'. Seems I'm doing something wrong since:

```
grep -F "Btr_0449"

Btr_0449a   447
Btr_0449    447
```

Comment: `grep '^Btr_0449\W'` will work here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to grep the exact match](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709912/how-to-grep-the-exact-match)

Answer (score 3):

This should do it:

```
grep -Fw "Btr_0449"
```

From the `grep` manpage:

"-w    Select  only  those  lines  containing  matches  that form whole words. "

Answer (score 1):

If you insist to use '-F' flag, then adding a space after your string will do.

`grep -F "Btr_0449 "`

For the future, you will get much better results if you'll use regex patterns, so for the above query, you could do:

`grep -e "Btr_0449\s"`

...which will match your string followed by any whitespace character (space, tab, new line, carriage return...)