# Search the exact matched line from a file with grep

Tags: unix

I have a property file with below contents.

```
mongodb.databasename=dbname
#mongodb.databasename=dbname
```

from this i need to take out the line which has only "mongodb.databasename=dbname". I tried with

```
cat app.properties | grep mongodb.databasename=dbname
```

but it retrieves both the line as a result. i tried with many options line -w, -F, -h but i couldn't get what i need. Could anyone help me how shouldi get only the exact matched line. I tried from this also "[How to make grep only match if the entire line matches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709912/how-to-make-grep-only-match-if-the-entire-line-matches)" but i couldn't get what i need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cat stack | grep -E '(^|\s)mongodb.databasename=dbname($|\s)'
```