# Regular Expressions - match entire line contents

Tags: regex

I want to use regular expressions to search for a line consisting of one single word.  Say the word was apple, and I am searching:

```
apple
banana
apple pear banana
apple banana
pear apple
pear
```

I only want it to match "apple".  I do not want to match apple just at the beginning of the line, but when the line is equal to "apple".

Edit: for those asking why I'm using regular expressions, I need to check for the word case-insensitively, thus I'm using `(?i)apple`

Edit2: I'm modifying the title to reflect that this can be used not just for a specific word, but anytime we are looking for the *entire* contents of a line, rather than just matching lines that *contain* the expression

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to achieve what I asked in the question - to match a single word line only.  If I do '(?i)apple' it will match all lines that contain "apple"

Comment: I've discovered a solution - I'm going to answer my own question since I haven't been able to find another answer.

Comment: Not a duplicate of that - the solution to that question will match all lines with words after "apple".

Comment: And I don't understand the downvotes - is the question not clear?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make grep only match if the entire line matches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709912/how-to-make-grep-only-match-if-the-entire-line-matches)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution after more experimentation - the answer is to search for the word at both the beginning (^) and end ($) of the line:

```
'^apple$'
```

Comment: A much better solution is to string compare it `== "apple"` Otherwise, for multi-line string, the anchors only match the beginning and end of string. For that you'd need `(?m)^apple$` which would find it on a line by itself. But, it still doesn't tell you much about it.

Answer (score 2):

Use anchors:

```
^apple$
```

Or compare them via string functions as there do not seem to be changing parts which would make regular expression kind of a must.

Comment: Thanks - that's what I just found.

Comment: I need the case insensitivity of regex, otherwise I would compare strings

Comment: @JoelM.: This might be a reason for the downvotes: you did not mention that you want it in the first place.