# Grep exact match with multple strings, no dash

Tags: grep

I have a list of genes like this one saved on a variable:

```
NOL6
NPPC
NPRL2
NRG1
NT5C1B
NUDT19
OSER1
PAEP
PARD3
PCDHA4
```

I want to `grep` all these genes at another list of the same type on a txt. I tried this:

```
grep -w "^$genes$" list.txt
```

The problem is that it returns to me genes with a dash `-` like this one similar to NT5C1B:

```
NT5C1B-RDH14
```

However, if I search the gene individually:

```
grep "^NT5C1B$" list.txt
```

I'll not obtain the gene with the dash but only:

```
NT5C1B
```

Is there any way to do this using `grep -w` or other command?

Comment: Replace `-w` with `-x`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make grep only match if the entire line matches?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4709925/3832970)

Comment: we need to see some text in the `list.txt` also, what is in your `$gene` variable? a single entry or all entries as you pasted in your first code block?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I think the question was closed probably too soon... "I'll not obtain the gene with the dash but only:...." I **guess** OP wants to get `Pattern-something` in the result. Also, we didn't see the input text, we don't know if it's `-x` case. Anyway, OP didn't describe the requirement clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `-x` as it only selects exact matches. `-w` can match a string if it has non-word constituent characters after the substring. See [grep(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep) .

Comment: That's it, thanks! In case there were more colums apart from the gene names like this: `chr1 NT5C1B`. Would it work?

Comment: @Swimmingbird It will only return exact matches. So assuming you want "chr1 NT5C1B" returned, then you would need to execute `grep -x "chr1 NT5C1B"`.

Comment: And in case I only want to grep the gene name (NT5C1B)?